# Add span inside anchor output using PHP's ob_get_contents function

Tags: php, html, wordpress, ob-start, ob-get-contents

## What I have:

A PHP function that outputs a log in/out link based on whether the user is correspondingly logged in/out.

```
<a href="foo">bar</a>
```

## What I need:

I need a span wrapped around the link text inside the anchor element.

```
<a href="foo"><span>bar</span></a>
```

## My code:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {

        ob_start();
        wp_loginout('index.php');
        $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        $items .= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';

    return $items;
}
```

I've checked the wp_loginout() function for a potential parameter but the two that exist do not apply:

```
<?php wp_loginout( $redirect, $echo ); ?>
```

## My question:

How can I wrap a span inside the anchor using a server-side approach. I don't want to have to resort to client-side approaches like JavaScript.

Comment: Why can't you just echo the code you need?

Comment: @AndrewWilson The code I need (the link) is dynamically produced by calling the wp_loginout() function. It automates a number of steps including detecting if the user is logged in/out, outputting the relevant link and nonce tokens for security. This is the reason I'm returning the output using a function rather than echoing it.

Comment: Sorry I can't help but I don't use WordPress.

Comment: add `wordpress`  tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

`wp_logout_url ( string $redirect = '' )` function instead of `wp_loginout('index.php')`

example,

```
    ob_start();
    wp_logout_url('index.php');
    $logoutlink= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $items .= '<a href="'.$logoutlink.'"'><span></span></a>;
```

use `is_user_logged_in()` to check weather user logged in or not.

```
ob_start();
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    wp_logout_url('index.php');
} else {
    site_url('index.php') 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the two functions you've used.

Comment: glad i can help. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-items-to-specific-wordpress-menus/  , this might come in handy for you